# Why Does My Object Not Show in Rendered Shading Mode?

Tags: rendering, uv, 3d-view, objects, render-layers

I have had this happen to me a few times prior but instead of just deleting the object and starting over I would like to know why it is that my objects appear in **Solid Shade Mode** and only a shadow appears in the **Rendered Shade Mode**?

I'm trying to UV Wrap the object and the wrapping never appears in the 3D viewport. I selected Textured Solid in the Shading Tab but image still does not show.

[image]

[image: Cube not showing in rendered shade mode]

Comment: (facepalm), I believe your object is the same color as the background by default, that may be the problem above other things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you have some render layers set up. The option to to preview the active render layer in the 3D view header has been enabled:

[image]

This will mean that if an object isn't assigned to this render layer the object will not appear in the rendered view. Disable this button to view all objects in the rendered view regardless of their render layer.

Comment: Thank you that was it! Do you know why my UV is not showing on the cube?

Comment: @Kay If that part of your question isn't already answered somewhere here http://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=Textured+view+cycles then I suggest asking a separate question with your .blend file attached.

Answer (score 0):

When this happened to me, it turned out that my material was not defined. Creating a new material was the solution.